# Java XML: ClassCastException class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredTextImpl cannot be cast to class javax.swing.text.Element

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax

Throw this program I'm trying to unzip my xml file and parse it using SAX, for the parsing part I have an exception which appeared about ClassCastException class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredTextImpl cannot be cast to class javax.swing.text.Element, here is my code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import net.lingala.zip4j.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
public class Parser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ZipException {
        String source = "C:\\Users\\java_program\\xml.zip";
        String destination = "C:\\Users\\java_program\\xml";
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);
        zipFile.extractAll(destination);
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(new File ("C:\\Users\\java_program\\xml\\xml.xml"));
            
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList productList = document.getElementsByTagName("product");
            for(int i = 0; i<productList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node product = productList.item(i);
                if (product.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element productElement = (Element) product; // the problem is here
                    NodeList productDetails = product.getChildNodes();
                    for(int j=0; j<productDetails.getLength(); j++) {
                        Node detail = productDetails.item(j);
                        if (product.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                            Element detailElement = (Element) detail; // the problem is here
                            System.out.println("      " + ((org.w3c.dom.Element) detailElement).getTagName() + ": " + detailElement.getAttributes());
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

My XML file have this structure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<import xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <products>
        <product>
            <article_sku>000c66dawt</article_sku>
            <brand>HUAWEI</brand>
            <brand_reference>HUAWEI-NEXUS-6P-64GO-ARGENT</brand_reference>
            <category>SMARTP</category>
            <ean13>6901443077359</ean13>
            <it_cpu_smartphone_type><![CDATA[Qualcomm Snapdragon S810]]></it_cpu_smartphone_type>
        </product>
        <product>
            <article_sku>000cfxlysl</article_sku>
            <brand>HERCULES</brand>
            <brand_reference>HERCULES-DJCONTROL-COMPACT</brand_reference>
            <category>PLATIN-1</category>
            <ean13>3362934745288</ean13>
        </product>
    </products>
</import>
```

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You imported the wrong `Element` class.
Change

```
import javax.swing.text.Element;
```

to

```
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
```

Also you create detail object which is a node and check that if the previously created product variable is an element and then cast detail to Element.

```
Node detail = productDetails.item(j);
if (product.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    Element detailElement = (Element) detail;
```

the product line:

```
  Node product = productList.item(i);
```

I think you should chacnge to conditional to `detail.getNodetype() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE`

Comment: because of another issue :)

Comment: You're the best !